# Tiny assembler translator for student project

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, code-translation

I am looking for small assembler translator for a student project. The problem is so that it is necessary to translate small portions of assembler (AT&T) syntax into machine code (x86 and/or x86_64) on the fly. I don't want to reinvent the wheel so I will be grateful for any links to ready implementations. Preference will be given to lightweight library with  simple interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/download.php) a look, although its a full assembler for x86 and x86_64, its opensource, which should easily allow you to integrate it, you can also have a look at [GAS](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html), which is also open source.

Finding an actual assembler library is gonna very difficult, as most are geared to JIT compilers, the best you'll find is [asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/).